# Probability of X given the sum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I am given that $X \sim P(\lambda)$, $Y \sim P(\gamma)$, and told to calculate the distribution of $P(X | X+Y = n)$

I proceed as follows

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(X=i|X+Y=n) &= \frac{P((X=i) \cap (X+Y = n))}{P(X+Y = n)} \\
&= \frac{P(X+Y=n | X=i) P(X=i)}{P(X+Y=n)}\\
&= \frac{P(Y=n-i)P(X=i)}{P(X+Y=n)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

We also know that $X+Y \sim P(\lambda + \gamma)$, thus:

$P(Y=n-i) = \frac{\gamma^{n-i} e^{-\gamma}}{(n-i)!}$

$P(X=i) = \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!}$

$P(X+Y=n) = \frac{(\lambda + \gamma)^n e^{\lambda + \gamma}}{n!}$

Hence,

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(X=i|X+Y = n) &= \frac{\gamma^{n-i} e^{-\gamma}}{(n-i)!} \frac{\lambda^i e^{-\lambda}}{i!} \frac{n!}{(\lambda + \gamma)^n e^{\lambda + \gamma}}\\
&= \binom{n}{k} \frac{\gamma^{n-i} \lambda^i}{(\lambda+\gamma)^n} e^{-2(\lambda + \gamma)}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

However, when I want to check that this indeed does sum to one over the range of the variable (notice that $R_X = \{0, .., n\}$):

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{\gamma^{n-i} \lambda^i}{(\lambda+\gamma)^n} e^{-2(\lambda + \gamma)} &= \frac{e^{-2(\lambda + \gamma)}}{(\lambda+\gamma)^n} \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \gamma^{n-i} \lambda^i \\
&=e^{-2(\lambda + \gamma)}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}$$

Its clear that I am doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You left out the minus sign in the exponent in $P(X+Y=n)$. (Also all your $k$'s should be $i$'s...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten minus sign from

$P(X+Y=n) = \frac{(\lambda + \gamma)^n e^{\lambda + \gamma}}{n!}$

It is supposed to be

$P(X+Y=n) = \frac{(\lambda + \gamma)^n e^{-\lambda - \gamma}}{n!}$

Multiply sum with $e^{2(\lambda + \gamma)}$ and sum adds up to one.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that the correct PMF for $X+Y$ is $$\Pr[X + Y = n] = e^{-(\lambda + \gamma)} \frac{(\lambda+\gamma)^n}{n!},$$ whereas in your solution you are missing the negative sign. The resulting correction will cause the exponential terms to cancel.  The result should be a binomial distribution for a suitable choice of parameters.